# Issue related to Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I need to append the data from responseLicensing (like expiryDate, cloudAccountName, cloudAccountId) to the responseSfdc data depending on the similar 'key' value.

Perform a lookup in the responseLicensing object using the key in an instance of responseSfdc and append some key-value pairs picked as a result of a successful lookup, to responseSfdc object.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 

var responseSfdc = [{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  }]

var responseLicensing = [{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  }]
---
{
    responseSfdc map (sfdc,i) -> {
        
    }
}
```

Output I need is something like this -

```
[{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null,
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null,
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  }]
```

Comment: You need to update the attributes on `responseSfdc` with the ones from `responseLicensing` for elements that match the exact `key`?

Comment: You can refer to the examples under the documentation. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-merge-multiple-payloads

Comment: There are several ways to solve it. you can use mergeWith or lambda function for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using function for readability and using default for safety check

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
var responseSfdc = [] // Assuming you have data for responseSfdc in array

var responseLicensing = [] // Assuming you have data for responseLicensing in an array

fun getLicenseInfo(key) = responseLicensing[?($.key == key)][0] 
---
responseSfdc map (item,index) -> (item) ++ 
  ((getLicenseInfo(item.key) default {}) - "key")
```

"`- key`" is to remove the extra field from responseLicensing variable before appending it to the result.
"`default {}`" preventing the Null error. If you don't have match, the `- key` will fail and you will get an exception like:

```
You called the function '-' with these arguments: 
  1: Null (null)
  2: String ("key")
```

**Another Option:**

Using **mergeWidth** while checking the match, you don't need to use **`-`** to remove duplicate element.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects
var responseSfdc = []
var responseLicensing = []
output application/json 
---
responseSfdc map ((sfdc) -> sfdc mergeWith 
   responseLicensing[?($.key == sfdc.key)][0])
```

Comment: The mergeWith() method seems the simplest one.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a work for the [leftJoin()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-leftjoin) function.

```
[%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import * from dw::core::Arrays

var responseSfdc = \[{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  }\]

var responseLicensing = \[{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  }\]
---
leftJoin( responseSfdc, responseLicensing,  (sfdc) -> sfdc.key, (license) -> license.key)  map ($.l ++ ($.r - "key"))][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 

var responseSfdc = [{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "contractEndDate": null,
    "product": {
      "productName": "ArtPro+ Subscription",
      "productCode": "ArtPro+S",
      "downloadURL": null,
      "upgradeProduct": null
    },
    "projectReference": null,
    "orderNumber": "O-0000001105",
    "orderCreationDate": "2020-07-14T07:48:04.000Z",
    "subscriptionName": null,
    "autoRenewal": null
  }]

var responseLicensing = [{
    "key": "SUBT00009925-1",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "SUBT00009925-2",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  }]
---
responseSfdc map () -> using (id = $.key)
  {
     a:$
  }.a
  ++
    {
        (responseLicensing filter ($.key == id)  map (responseLicensingValue) -> {
      cloudAccountId : responseLicensingValue.cloudAccountId,
      cloudPublicName: responseLicensingValue.cloudPublicName
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take.

```
responseSfdc map ((item, index) -> 
    item ++ (responseLicensing[?($.key == item.key)][0] - "key")
)
```

If you find you have more duplicate keys you need removed from the output you can add them after  `- key`.  Alternately there is a [DW writer property for JSON](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-json#writer-properties-for-json): `[duplicateKeyAsArray]` that you can use to output an array of values instead of duplicate keys.